# Best file format workflow for Final Cut Pro 7 on Maveriks

Tags: video, final-cut-pro, workflow, production

i am having problems exporting my project in Final Cut Pro 7.
All the clips i am working on are mov in h.264.
I want to export correctly a master file, that will be converted in web format, hd... with MPEG Streamclip.
But i am experiencing problems with frame freezes, and coding problems.

Can you suggest me a tutorial, a guide, a book, a video course where to learn the perfect workflow for video production with Final Cut Pro 7 on Maveriks?
Or do you have any suggestions to help me?

Thank you guys.

Luca

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking.  Why are you trying to use MPEG Streamclip instead of simply exporting in the format you need?  Final Cut Pro has built in encoder support for outputting in your final web formats of your choice for a pretty good number of formats.

Comment: I ended exporting in APPLE PRO RES HQ and then converting in MPEG Streamclip.
Final Cut Pro was giving me bugged files!

Answer (score 2):

Likely your issues were stemming from trying to edit with H264 files.  This is something that FCP hates!  Convert all your h264 footage to ProRes before you start editing (using Compressor, MPEG Streamclip, or the awesome Magic Bullet Grinder) and then edit with the ProRes files.  Output your final 'Master File' as ProRes and then use Compressor to encode that file to various formats for delivery.

Answer (score 1):

In FCP7 when importing the files you should be using the "log and transfer" option, you need to change the import format to ProRes (As stated above), do all your editing and then exporting using FCP7 or Compressor to a Master ProRes or which ever other format you want to use. This is how I used to edit my Canon 7D files before FCPX

If you can use FCPX you can natively edit the h.264 files and export directly, this is how I work currently with .MOV files from my Canon 7D

Comment: Cheers for the edit Pat, I was at work and thought it was the right wording